# Is it possible to generate an extra file with ng generate?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

For most of the components I have in my app, I need to generate manually a `theme.scss` file manually.

As I'm a lazy developer (aren't we all?), I would like to find a way to make angular-cli generate this `theme.scss` file each time a new component is created with `ng g c mycomp` (mycomp for the example).

Instead of this:

```
mycomp.component.html
mycomp.component.scss
mycomp.component.ts
```

Having that:

```
mycomp.component.html
mycomp.component.scss
mycomp.component.theme.scss
mycomp.component.ts
```

Is there a way?

Thanks and hi (why this website is removing my hi all the time?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can modify the `generate component` behaviour to include an extra file in `angular-cli`, but you can create your own custom schematics to create a component defined in the way you prefer.

I'd suggest you to have a look at this [post](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/%EF%B8%8F-how-to-create-your-first-custom-angular-schematics-with-ease-%EF%B8%8F-bca859f3055d) which explains to you quite in a detailed way how to create a schematics.

Comment: I was looking into this in fact, but was not really sure that was meant for this, as all the tutorials I found was using it when building... I will take a look art the link you provided, thanks :)